# How do I align these images with the top of the table?

Tags: tables, graphics, positioning

I am struggling to align these two images with the one in the middle from the top instead of from the bottom. Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Please post your code as `MWE`, i.e., from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: Please copy and paste your code into the question rather than screenshot and make it a MWE.

Comment: Try `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}`
...
`\includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=t]{image}` The `valign=t` should do it, I think.

Comment: You can also use `\raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox-\height}{...}`, but adjustbox is easier.